# Visualforce redirect

Tags: visualforce

I have a login page with username and password and forgot password link on salesforce community , when a user enters a wrong password it is throwing error. When the error is thrown and I click on the forgot password link the page is refreshing instead of redirecting to forgot password page. Can anyone help in resolving the issue?

```
public PageReference forgotpswd()
{
     pageReference pg = new pageReference(/apex/pagename);
     Page.setRedirect(true);
     return pg;
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:commandLink value="Forgot Password?" action="{!forgotpswd}" />
```

Comment: can you update your question with your visualforce page code?

Comment: What is the value of  `LINK`?

Comment: vf page  link  ---     /apex/pagelink.

Comment: this seems to be valid code and it working fine at my side. one think is different is make sure you have pg.setRedirect(true); instead of Page.setRedirect(true);

Comment: i have corrected it but not working ........ does i need to link  error message page to this forgot password link ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with alternative approach?

```
<apex:commandLink value="Forgot Password?" action="{!URLFOR('/apex/pagelink')}" />
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Put the page reference return URL in single quotes.

```
Pagereference pg = new Pagereference ('/apex/pagename');
```

Comment: Is your problem resolved by putting single quotes in the return URL?

Answer (score 0):

my issue go resolved my jusing adding 'site URL'in page reference

Comment: If this resolved the issue, why wouldn't this be a  valid answer ?

Comment: I already posted the same thing putting the single quotes as an answer to the question.. Doesn't make any sense to discuss. The problem was the URL in Pagereference was not kept in quotes, and now if the problem is solved. We can close the question marking my answer as correct answer to question.